# json data on server side (grails controller) is null

Tags: jquery, json, grails

I send data in JSON to the server like this:

```
        var username = $("#usernameField").val();
        var email = $("#emailField").val();
        var password = $("#passwordField").val();
        var parameters = {
            'username':username,
            'email':email,
            'password':password
        };
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            dataType:"JSON",
            url: doRegistrationUrl,  
            data: parameters,  
            success: function(answer) {  
                console.log(answer);
            }  
        });
```

this is the function who gets the data (a grails controller)

```
def doRegistration() {
    def userdata = request.JSON;
    printf("DataInController: "+userdata);
    render userdata.username;
}
```

Url

```
var doRegistrationUrl = '${createLink(action:"doRegistration", controller:"registration")}';
```

however, the userdata is always null, the data doesnt get to the server. I cant see why. Anybody can help with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but that didnt do it

Comment: and you are actually sending the request?  are you sending to the same domain from which the js is loaded?

Comment: try ....   def doRegistration(request)

Comment: doRegistration(request) didnt work, same as doRegistration(def request), I dont know if I really send the request, how can I find out? I think it´s the same domain tho, I added the doRegistrationUrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data parameters are just ordinary HTTP request parameters sent via POST. You deal with it just like every other controller action. Try:

```
def doRegistration() {
    def userdata = params
    printf("DataInController: "+userdata);
    render userdata.username;
}
```

Comment: yes, that did it, thank you. I dont understand why params.parameters doesnt work tho.

Comment: @dan params is a GrailsParameterMap object and it's a map. With groovy syntax `params['parameters']` is equal to `params.parameters` and since you don't have `parameters` key it's empty.